# Not equal mixed second partial derivative on an open connected set?

Tags: partial-derivative, examples-counterexamples

It is all known that there are some functions whose mixed second parital derivatives exist but not equal at a single point, I am thinking what is about on a connected set.

To be clear, Is there any function $f$ defined on an **open connected** set $D\subset \mathbf{R}^2$ such that

1. For all $(x,y)\in D$,
   $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial y},\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$$
   exist.
2. For all $(x,y)\in D$,
   $$ \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial y}\neq \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}.$$